# Cant reverse Javascript simple Diff

Tags: javascript

Im using _ to do a simple diff in javascript. I have 2 objects that are the same until someone changes a text field, then there is the old object and the new object. (im trying to create an audit log to keep track of any fields that are changed).

Here is my code so far.

```
var o1 = $scope.historicSite,
    o2 = $scope.newsite;

var old_value = _.omit(o1, function(v, k) {
    return o2[k] === v;
});

console.log("old value :", old_value);
```

This is working fine and for example if i change only the "site name" field i get back

```
{site_name: "Old Value"}
```

from the function.

I am needing to get both the old value (which i get above) and the new value so i can store them, ive tried flipping the o1 and o2 variables but it just returns the whole object! Is the away to reverse this so i can get the new value as well as the old?

Thank you

Comment: Alternative: `Object.keys(o1).reduce((o, k) => Object.assign(o, o2[k] === o1[k] ? {} : {[k]: { old: o1[k], 'new': o2[k]}}), {});` will give you `{site_name: { old: "Old Value", new: "New Value"}}` - no library required :p

Comment: `ive tried flipping the o1 and o2 variables but it just returns the whole object!` - you did something wrong in that case, because changing o1/o2 in `_.omit` gives you new values only - see https://jsfiddle.net/br94nb3a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the keys from the 'diff' and create a object from the new values:

Something like:

```
const new_values = Object.keys(old_value).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    accumulator[key] = o2[key];
    return accumulator;
}, {})
```